# How to get count of input messages on IBM MQ?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to get count of incoming messages  in IBM MQ. When I getting data with `amqsmon`. It returns `PutCount` but it's always 0: `PutCount [0,0]`, even when queue is under load.

Are there other tools or instruments to get statistics?

Comment: MQ itself has a statistics feature. It needs to be enabled by your MQ admin and then the QM will put statistics info into message onto the queue SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE.

Comment: Thanks, i'm already using this feature, but the problem is that not all statistics gets in the message for SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE: PutCount [0,0] is always contains only null-values, even when i put in the queue hundreds of messages.